# Casting to object in .NET reference source

Tags: c#, .net, object

I was going through the [OperatingSystem.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/operatingsystem.cs) file in the .NET reference source and noted this code in [line 50](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/operatingsystem.cs,50):

```
if ((Object) version == null)
```

`version` is an object of class [`Version`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/version.cs.html#0c15515dfe051d35), which means `version` derives from `Object`. If that is so, isn't it redundant casting to `Object`? Wouldn't it be the same as this?

```
if (version == null)
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

No, it's not equivalent - because `Version` overloads the `==` operator.

The snippet which casts the left operand to `Object` is equivalent to:

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(version, null))
```

... rather than calling the `operator==` implementation in `Version`. That's likely to make a nullity check as its first action anyway, but this just bypasses the extra level.

In other cases, this can make a very significant difference. For example:

```
string original = "foo";
string other = new string(original.ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(original == other); // True
Console.WriteLine((object) original == other); // False
```

Comment: @afaolek: No need to go through the source - just look at the documentation and you'll see the equality operator.

Comment: Using the sample in your answer, what will be the result of `Console.WriteLine((object)original == (object)other);`?

Comment: @afaolek: False again - that doesn't change anything, because it will still use the reference comparison, basically.

Comment: I just thought about it, too. The two casts are basically two different (temporary) object references pointing to two different locations, right?

Comment: @afaolek: The casts end up with the same references as `original` and `other` - just with a compile-time type of `object` instead of `string`, which affects overload resolution.

Comment: Curious: in the source, the == operator calls `Equals(Version obj)`, and inside `Equals` there's a line: `if (obj == null)`

Comment: @Dennis_E: In http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs, the first thing that `==` does is check for `ReferenceEquals`. I'm not sure what you're referring to at the moment, but I suggest you ask a new question if you're still confused.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, but if it is not null, it will call Equals, and the first thing Equals does is call `if (obj == null)`

Comment: Oh, I see it now. There can only be one loop :)

Comment: @Dennis_E I wrote a small blog post about this question here http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/11/cast-to-object-before-comparing-to-null/